# How to delete current row with jquery datatable plugin with multiple tables in the page

Tags: jquery, datatables

I use datatable plugin in a website.
Normally I have only 1 datatable per page but in a special display I have 2 datable.

**Actually I have this code**

```
var oTable = $('.datatable').dataTable({
    'sPaginationType':'full_numbers',
    "iDisplayLength": 50,
    "oLanguage": {
        "sUrl": "js/locales/dataTables.french.txt"
    }
});

/* Add a click handler to the rows - this could be used as a callback */
$(".delete-ajax").click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var answer = confirm("Supprimer l'élément ?")
    if (answer){
    var loading = $('.loading-notification');
    loading.removeClass('hidden');
        $(oTable.fnSettings().aoData).each(function (){
            $(this.nTr).removeClass('row_selected');
        });
        $(event.target).parents('tr').addClass('row_selected');
        var url = $(this).attr('href');
        var id = $(this).attr('data-ajax');
        var anSelected = fnGetSelected( oTable );
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: url,
        data: "delete=true&id="+ id,
        async : true,
        success: function(msg) {
            loading.addClass('hidden');
            oTable.fnDeleteRow( anSelected[0] );
            }
        });
    }
});
/* Get the rows which are currently selected */
function fnGetSelected( oTableLocal ){
    var aReturn = new Array();
var aTrs = oTableLocal.fnGetNodes();
for ( var i=0 ; i<aTrs.length ; i++ ){
    if ( $(aTrs[i]).hasClass('row_selected') ){
        aReturn.push( aTrs[i] );
    }
}
return aReturn;
}
```

This code work well when I have only 1 datatable but when I have more I obtain In my console :

```
k is undefined
[Stopper sur une erreur]   h=a._iDisplayEnd;if(a.oFeatures.bServe...push(a.aoOpenRows[k].nTr)}}else{d[0]=
```

Any idea on how to solve this problem ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is how you can delete a row in the table (regardless the number of amount of tables in page)

I got two table in same page

I am not sure about how good is the id that you gave to the table, but if its ".datatable" then:

Add this function to your page

```
$(".datatable tbody").delegate("tr", "click", function () {
    var iPos = oTable.fnGetPosition(this);
    if (iPos !== null) {
        oTable.fnDeleteRow(iPos);//delete row
    }
});
```

Comment: Does this also delete the row from the database? I noticed from the datatables site the implementation of 'remove' will simply hide the row. Then upon navigating away from the page, and navigating back, the previously hidden ow comes back again.

Comment: Nope, this only deletes from client, in addition you should handle the deletion on your server side...

Answer (score 3):

I am just sharing how I did it.

```
$(".delete-ajax").click(function(){
 var row = $(this).closest("tr").get(0);
 //ajax code goes here to delete row in the database
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: url,
    data: "delete=true&id="+ id,
    async : true,
    success: function(msg) {
          loading.addClass('hidden');
          oTable.fnDeleteRow(oTable.fnGetPosition(row));
        }
    });
}
```

UPDATE: dataTable v1.10
I now use:

```
var row = $(this).closest("tr");
oTable.row(row).remove().draw();
```

For more details see: https://datatables.net/reference/api/row().remove()

Comment: So, you delete first the row and then the record in the database?. are there any problems y you do it reverse?

Comment: Tank you, i'll try this way.

Comment: If you're having problem making this to work, let me know, I would gladly help. :)