# table.rows().remove() does not work if serverSide: true

Tags: jquery, datatables

when i try to remove row from **datatable** 
I simply use this

```
    var table = $('#tbl').DataTable();
   table.rows().remove().draw();
```

its working but if i set datatable

```
"processing": true,"serverSide": true
```

than

```
table.rows().remove().draw();
```

it will not remove any row form datatable

Comment: Possible duplicate of **[jQuery Datatables: how to delete the row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10214307/jquery-datatables-how-to-delete-the-row)** Also you can go through this **[forum link](https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/30614/deleting-rows-server-side)**

Answer (score 4):

Method [`rows.remove()`](https://datatables.net/reference/api/rows().remove()) is pure client side. If you enable `serverSide: true` then you need to handle deletions manually. For example use Ajax to delete rows. Note that you need support from your server side also to remove rows.

Example code:

```js
$('#delete').on('click', function() {
    var selectedRows = table.rows( $('#table tr.active') ).data().to$();

    $.ajax({
        url: url_to_delete_rows,
        method: 'POST',
        data: { rows: selectedRows.toArray() },
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function( data, status, xhr ) {
            table.rows( $('#table tr.active') ).remove().draw(false);
        }
    });
});
```

For more information please check this [link](https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/30614/deleting-rows-server-side).