# Getting rowIndex of jquery data table inside renderer function on link click?

Tags: jquery, html, datatables

This is my small code snippet for adding columns in data table.I want to get pass the row index of datable in "addCustomer" function.
 Basically if i have 100 customer in datable and when i click on  labelCustName link, i want to get that rown index in addCustomer Function?

```
 "aoColumns": [     { "mDataProp": "checkbox","bSortable": false,"bSearchable": false},
                   { "mDataProp": "Subject","bSearchable": true,
                 "fnRender": function ( o, val ) {
                 var custId =o.aData["custId"];
                 var labelCustName = o.aData["CustName"];
                 var dept = o.aData["CustDept"];
                 custId = "<a href= \"javascript:addCustomer(curRoWId);\">"labelCustName "</a>";  
                 return custId;
                   }
            }
           ]
```

Comment: how about this ? http://stackoverflow.com/a/8254752/617373 instead of `a href` using delegate

Comment: it gives error missing ) after argument list in firebug once i add the function

Comment: I updated(added closing `);`) my answer at that link (did jslint to the function) , try now...

Comment: It works Daniel.Thanks. Just want to confirm is there any way we van get from fnRender function parameters?

Comment: dunno , you can take a look at the `o` and `val` in the browser debugger (add watch)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can get the rowindex insise render function with

```
    o.iDataRow
```