# how to remove or delete a row in jquery datatable based on condition

Tags: jquery, datatables

I'm trying to remove/delete rows from datatable  based on some condition. I tried the following code.

```
 rowCallback: function (row, data, index) {
                if (data["ServiceID"] == 0) {
                    $(row).remove();
                }
            },
```

which doesn't seem to work. Although `$(row).hide()` is working fine but it just hide rows does not delete or remove it from the datatable.

Answer (score 1):

This function not deleting row, just setting its inside as null.

```
$(row).html("");// not deleting setting inside null.
```

You can use this way, while creating elements(initializing) you can't remove row it self, but you can set it as null. If you want to remove after initialization, you can do this:

1) to deleted items add them inside an array;

2) After initializon, remove from datatable with remove() function and then use draw function to re-draw table content.

or

alternate way previously create datatable, remove the unasked datas.

Comment: i tried  $(row).delete() showing  TypeError: $(...).delete is not a function error . i using condition in rowCallback

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `remove()` method, after removing, you need to `redraw` the table

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var table = $('#example').DataTable();

    $('#example tbody').on( 'click', 'tr', function () {
        if ( $(this).hasClass('selected') ) {
            $(this).removeClass('selected');
        }
        else {
            table.$('tr.selected').removeClass('selected');
            $(this).addClass('selected');
        }
    } );

    $('#button').click( function () {
        table.row('.selected').remove().draw( false );
    } );
} );
```

check datatables remove row [docs](https://datatables.net/examples/api/select_single_row.html) or working [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nagesh521/8e1f62d4/3/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `fnDeleteRow` function together with `fnGetPosition` function.

```
 var ePos = oTable.fnGetPosition('THE_ROW_ELEMENT');   
 rowCallback: function (ePos, data, index) {
 if (data["ServiceID"] == 0) {
                oTable.fnDeleteRow(ePos);
            }
},
```

Iknow this is a different approach but thought it might help you.

[The answer to this question might help you to understand the functionality of these functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8098244/how-to-delete-current-row-with-jquery-datatable-plugin-with-multiple-tables-in-t)